# Google Sheets - IF columns contains text and another columns contains number return total value of number column

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, text, sum, numbers

I am trying to see if I am able to get the hours from one column only if it matches a word that is another column.

For example in the sheet link attached, if the word is Operations (Column A) I want to get the sum of all the hours (Column B) that correlate with that word.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-1QCZsNTZ5xDcDryv8qg0YPtsoY3Erjz7ZNGUXds7HY/edit

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
=SUM(IFNA(FILTER(B:B,A:A=E1)))
```

OR

```
=SUMIF(A:A,E1,B:B)
```

- Cell E1 has the word selection in the sample here

[image]